# CFAutoRelease() -like behavior on iOS6

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, core-foundation

I have a method that creates an ABRecordRef, sets its properties and returns the ref.

I'm encountering a crash when I use CFAutoRelease because I need to support iOS <7. how would I go about to properly releasing this?

```
-(ABRecordRef) myRecord{
 ABRecordRef newRecord = ABPersonCreate();
//some setting here
return CFAutoRelease(newRecord); //how to release here?
}
```

Comment: There is no `CFAutoRelease`.

Comment: Apparently there is, in 10.9 and iOS 7. (I didn't know, either.)

Comment: TIL. It's not documented yet, but it is mentioned in the iOS 7 API diffs: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/iOS70APIDiffs/

Comment: See Mike Ash's most recent blog post on this very topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For CoreFoundation references, I actually wouldn't release that reference in your `myRecord` method.  Instead I would define the interface such that the caller of `myRecord` owns the reference and is responsible for releasing it.

Comment: Make sure to name the method correctly. In this case it should be something like `newRecord`. By beginning with `new`, you are making it clear that the object has a retain that must be balanced.

Comment: That's true, you should try to follow the 'Create Rule' when working with CoreFoundation.  I would actually name the method `CreateRecord' or 'myRecordCreate'.  Here's a link to CoreFoundation's Ownership Policy which has more information including the 'Create Rule'.  https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/corefoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html

Comment: You might be able to cast to `id` and call `-autorelease` on it, too. (There's another question here with that as the accepted answer.)

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to build an own autorelease function for Core Foundation objects like this:

```
inline CFTypeRef MyAutorelease(CFTypeRef obj) { 
    id __autoreleasing result = CFBridgingRelease(obj); 
    return (__bridge CFTypeRef)result; 
}
```

With `__autoreleasing`, you force the object to end up in the autorelease pool.

Comment: Actually, the way Mike has shown does not use `__autoreleasing`. The code above originates from my comment on his blog post.

Comment: Ah. I guess you wrote after I read his. Yours and his are different style. Your follow up question is a good one

Comment: @TammoFreese This code crashes when using `Optimization Level` `-Os`. Any idea why?